# I have an error during a build to android in ionic cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, build

When I run a commend "ionic cordova build android", i have error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'io.ionic.starter'
```

I have a Firebase in my project. I found some solutions, but it's not working.

Comment: First change package on yours project from ionic (io.ionic.starter) to yours own and generate firebase own google-services.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id in the google-services.json should be like the id in the config.xml file.